# How to minimize object size of a large list of strings

Tags: memory

**Update:**

The discussion below was based on a made up example when objects are created in session. C.E. was absolutely right to point out that *Mathematica* can do the same trick and share objects. However, the question is inspired by reading large datasets from files. In this case, both **MemoryInUse** and **ByteCount** will show the same result. Suppose we create a matrix of strings:

```
m1 = MemoryInUse[];
x=Table["String", {10000}, {100}];
ByteCount@x
MemoryInUse[] - m1

(* 49040080 *)
(* 9042656 *)
```

Obviously, the trick with memory sharing works. Let's write this to file and read it back.

```
Export["mat.csv", x, "CSV"];
m1 = MemoryInUse[];
x1 = Import["mat.csv", "CSV"];
MemoryInUse[] - m1
ByteCount@x1
x1===x

(* 49044432 *)
(* 49040080 *)
(* True *)
```

Apparently, *Mathematica* is using full space now (and even more for something else??) to store the matrix in memory. Any ideas how to force *Mathematica* to be less greedy after reading from file?

**Original post:**

I am trying to figure out the right way to work with large datasets. The problem is a huge memory overhead associated with a list of repeated strings in Mathematica. Specifically, I am comparing the memory management with R and it looks like Mathematica is far more greedy. Example: let's make a vector (or list) of one element which is a string of one character.

**R**

```
object.size(rep("1",1)) is 96 bytes
```

**Mathematica**

```
ByteCount@{"1"} is 88 bytes
```

So we are good here. But let's see what happens when you do 100 elements.

**R**

```
object.size(rep("1",100)) is 888 bytes
```

**Mathematica**

```
ByteCount@Table ["1", 100] is 4896 bytes
```

So we are using lot more memory in Mathematica now. Pushing it to the limits, let's do 1,000,000

**R**

```
object.size(rep("1",1e6)) is 8,000,088 bytes
```

**Mathematica**

```
ByteCount@Table ["1", 1*^6] is 48,000,080 bytes
```

All in all, Mathematica wants about 6 times more memory to store this simple list than R. What happens if we make the string longer? Let's do a 100 character string.

**R**

```
object.size(rep(strrep("1",100),1e6)) is 8,000,208 bytes
```

**Mathematica**

```
ByteCount@Table[StringJoin[Table["1", 100]], 1*^6] is 144,000,080 bytes
```

Now R uses almost the same amount of memory as for the short string, but Mathematica uses an order of magnitude larger. Apparently, R understand that this is a repeating object and simply stores just one instance, while Mathematica stores all of them.

For datasets and list of lists it is very important as usually there is a fixed list of string elements you use (names of categories, states, other features) and they are repeated many times. When importing such data set in R, it explicitly uses factor type, when the list of all instances is stored ones, and then the vector is simply a list of indices in that list. However, even when we are not using factor type in R, we have just seen that it still uses the same logic and stores such vectors much more efficiently.

Can we emulate this in Mathematica? The problem is that of course, I don't want a brute force method when I read all the elements, make a unique list, and then make my own index. This would make dataset convenience go away. I would like to have a solution which works relatively seamlessly when used -- in other words I still have a sort of association or a dataset with multiple columns (some strings, some numbers etc.) that is memory optimized.

Comment: You can use the `Share` function to detect duplicate subexpressions and share their storage.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you! Exactly right!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation for `ByteCount` states that

> ByteCount does not take account of any sharing of subexpressions. The
>   results it gives assume that every part of the expression is stored
>   separately. ByteCount will therefore often give an overestimate of the
>   amount of memory currently needed to store a particular expression.
>   When you manipulate the expression, however, subexpressions will often
>   stop being shared, and the amount of memory needed will be close to
>   the value returned by ByteCount.

So what you are measuring is what the byte count would be if repetition is not taken into account, but it does not tell you how much memory *Mathematica* actually allocates. For that we can use a different approach:

```
Clear[data];
mem = MemoryInUse[];
data = Table["1", 1*^6];
MemoryInUse[] - mem
```

> `8002664`

Which is almost the same as R's 8,000,208 bytes.

If you explicitly tell *Mathematica* that this is a list a repeated elements you can save some more memory, but not a lot in this case:

```
Clear[data];
mem = MemoryInUse[];
data = ConstantArray["1", 1*^6];
MemoryInUse[] - mem
```

> `7999080`

Comment: That's great! Didn't know about this trick with ByteCount. However, the bigger question here is how can an overhead with string storage be minimized when reading from a file. Then both memory in use and bytecount are the same for Mathematica. I will update the question.

Comment: @Stitch ok. There is something called packed arrays which perhaps could have been of use if this were a table of numerical data, but for strings I don't know of any way to "go back" once you've lost the optimization.

Answer (score 4):

If the strings are repeated frequently and the order of the data is not critical, store the [`Tally`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html) of the data.

```
mem = MemoryInUse[];
data = Transpose[{Table["1", 5*^5], Table["2", 5*^5]}] // Flatten;
MemoryInUse[] - mem

(*  8003392  *)

mem = MemoryInUse[];
tally = Tally[data];
MemoryInUse[] - mem

(*  2656  *)
```

The **sorted data** can be reconstructed from the `Tally`

```
Flatten[Table @@@ tally] === (data // Sort)

(*  True  *)
```